# Workaround Argument must be a range error when using SUMIF + FILTER

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, sumifs, google-query-language

| Col A | Col B | Col C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | back | 1 |
| a | back | 1 |
| b |  |  |
| b | draw | 1 |
| c | back | 1 |
| c |  |  |
| d | draw | 1 |
| d | draw | 1 |
| e | draw | 1 |

In Column E I put the values from Column A using `UNIQUE` and sorting with `SORT`:

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(A:A))
```

In Column F I tried to put a single formula in the first row, to sum each of the total values in Col C according to some filters:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E1:E="","",SUMIF(
              FILTER(A1:A,(B1:B<>"draw")*(C1:C<>"")),
              E1:E,
              FILTER(C1:C,(B1:B<>"draw")*(C1:C<>""))
)))
```

But I get the error:

```
Argument must be a range.
```

Expected Result:

| Col E | Col F |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2 |
| c | 1 |

Is there a way to make the filters become ranges or how should I proceed to avoid this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(A1:C, "select A,sum(C) where not B matches 'draw|^$' group by A label sum(C)''")
```

[image]

Comment: What is purpose of `|^$` in where clause `'draw|^$'`? Can you please tell little?

Comment: @Harun24hr `^$` in regex is equivalent to a null value eg it's the same as `where B is not null`. you can understand the whole  `where not B matches 'draw|^$'` as `where B <> 'draw' or B is not null`